# Attempting to edit a datatable nested inside of an editable datatable (Ajax Error I think)

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am attempting to make a nested (Through row expansion) data table editable which is inside of another editable datatable. It appears to be having a problem with the ajax rowEdit event. When I only have one datatable as editable e.g. comment out the nested ajax tag it works. But when I try to use both It returns an error saying :

Method not found: com.aglabexpress.Admin.Billing.CompleteInvoiceController@1146df77.editInvoiceItem(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)"

Is this because of the double ajax events?

How do I rectify this while keeping both tables editable?

HTMLX:

```
<h:form id="mainForm" >
<p:dataTable  id="mainFormTable" editable="true" value="#{completeInvoiceController.labNumberBill}" var="lab" paginator="true" rows="10" rowStyleClass="#{lab.colorStatus}">
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{completeInvoiceController.editBill}"  />
<p:column>
   <p:rowToggler/>
 </p:column>
    ...
    ...
    <p:column headerText="Date" footerText="Date">
       <p:cellEditor>
         <f:facet name="output">
             <p:outputLabel value="#{lab.creationDateString}" />
         </f:facet>
         <f:facet name="input">
             <p:calendar value="#{lab.creationDate}" />
          </f:facet>
         </p:cellEditor>
   </p:column>
   ...
   ...
   <p:column headerText="Edit">
        <p:rowEditor />
   </p:column>
<p:rowExpansion>
   <p:dataTable value="#{lab.invoiceItems}" var="item" editable="true">
        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{completeInvoiceController.editInvoiceItem}" />
           ...
           ...                 
         <p:column headerText="Description" footerText="Description">
               <p:cellEditor>
                  <f:facet name="output">
                      <p:outputLabel value="#{item.description}" />
                  </f:facet>
                   <f:facet name="input">
                      <p:inputText value="#{item.description}" />
                   </f:facet>
                 </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                   ...
                   ...
                 <p:column headerText="Edit">
                     <p:rowEditor />
                  </p:column>
               </p:dataTable>
         </p:rowExpansion>
```

Beans

```
public void editInvoiceItem(RowEditEvent event){
    InvoiceItemConstructor itc = (InvoiceItemConstructor) event.getObject();
    if(cih == null){
        cih = new CompleteInvoiceHelper();
    }
    cih.updateItem(itc);
}

public void editBill(RowEditEvent event){
    CompleteInvoiceLabNumberBill bill = (CompleteInvoiceLabNumberBill) event.getObject();
    if(cih == null){
        cih = new CompleteInvoiceHelper();
    }
    cih.updateBill(bill);
}
```

Comment: Try PrimeFaces 7, PrimeFaces 0.2 is not supported anymore

Comment: I would update the primefaces, but the dev before me made adjustments to the old primefaces source code to allow something but I have no idea what. So I'm afraid I'm stuck with this version until I feel confident in finding out what it was.

Comment: Ok, you did not get the hint.... specify the version you DO use, and TRY a newer version, just to see if it still fails. And create an mcve so if someone wants to try to reproduce, they have exactly the same code as you. Please also read [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace your nested datatable event method signature to

```
public void editInvoiceItem(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
```

> Is this because of the double ajax events?

Yes. This is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3876) (which had been originally reported for nested `p:tabView`) which seems to be fixed since PrimeFaces 5.0.

You can find further information in a thread (from July 2013) of the [PrimeFaces forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=32544)

Comment: This works, but I also had to set an <f:attribute value="#{item}" name="invoice" /> and retreive the object through event.getComponent().getAttributes().get(“invoice”)